# Using Hook in a Loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom `useOrganisation` hook to fetch and manipulate data from my API which look something along the lines of:

```
export function useOrganisation({ organisationId }) {
    const [organisation, setOrganisation] = useState()

    // Load organisation
    useEffect(() => {
        loadOrganisation({ organisationId, setOrganisation })
    }, [organisationId])

    return {
        organisation,
        setOrganisation
    }
}

async function loadOrganisation({ organisationId, setOrganisation }) {
    const data = await fetchOrganisationData(organisationId)
    setOrganisation(data)
}
```

This works well when I call it from within a component where I need to display information for a single organisation, because I use the hook to fetch that one specific organisation, however, when I want to use it on a dashboard-like page to load multiple organisations simultaneously, I'm unable to do so since I cannot call the hook from within a look like such:

```
export default function OrganisationsDashboard() {
    const [organisations, setOrganisations] = useState([])

    const organisationIds = ['org1', 'org2', 'org3']
    organisationIds.forEach(orgId => {
        setOrganisations(prevState => {
            const { organisation } = useOrganisation(orgId)

            const stateCopy = [...prevState]
            copy.push(organisation)
            return copy
        })
    })
}
```

What is the correct way to re-use the hook logic when needing to load multiple organisations into an array like in the mock component above?

Comment: Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. The official documentation may help you: [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your hook, to fetch a list of organizations, like this:

```
export function useOrganisation({ organisationIds }) {
    const [organisations, setOrganisations] = useState([]);

    // Load organisations
    useEffect(() => {
        loadOrganisations({ organisationIds, setOrganisations })
    }, [organisationIds])

    return {
        organisations,
        setOrganisations
    }
}

async function loadOrganisations({ organisationIds, setOrganisations }) {
    const orgs = [];
    for(let i=0; i < organisationIds.length; i++) {
      const data = await fetchOrganisationData(organisationIds[i]);
      orgs.push(data);
    }
    setOrganisations(orgs);
}
```

This can be used, in a component to get a single org, or in a dashboard to show multiple organizations, without having to use the hook in a loop.

Or, as using hooks in a loop is not recommended,  you can write a `useEffect` within your dashboard component to fetch a list of organizations and reuse some of your code. Like this:

```
export function useOrganisation({ organisationId }) {
    const [organisation, setOrganisation] = useState()

    // Load organisation
    useEffect(() => {
        const org = loadOrganisation({ organisationId });
       setOrganisation(org);
    }, [organisationId])

    return {
        organisation,
        setOrganisation
    }
}

export async function loadOrganisation({ organisationId }) {
    const data = await fetchOrganisationData(organisationId)
    return data;
}

export default function OrganisationsDashboard() {
    const [organisations, setOrganisations] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       const organisationIds = ['org1', 'org2', 'org3'];
       fetchOrganisations(organisationIds);
    }, []);
    
    async fetchOrganisations(orgIds) {
       const orgs = [];
       for(let i=0; i < orgIds.length; i++) {
          let org = await loadOrganisation({organisationId: orgIds[i]});
        orgs.push(org);  
       }
       setOrganisations(orgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to re-use existing logic instead of re-writing the entire hook changing the internal data structure. The actual hook logic is much more complicated and would break with this.

Comment: There will some tradeoffs there, you might want to write a `useEffect`, in your dashboard application then, to fetch orgs, as using hooks in a loop is not recommended